# Google AppScript not conecting to GmailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a simple AppScript to filter out gmail messages.
However, I'm unable to authorise the script to use GmailApp for some reason.

I've read the relevant documentation and it says that there is nothing special that needs to be done when using the default GCP project. Any idea what I'm missing?

Sample code that doesn't run (and taken from the guides in the documenation):

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  if (response.labels.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No labels found.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Labels:');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = response.labels[i];
      Logger.log('- %s', label.name);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the response I get after "giving" authorisation in the pop-up window:
[App Blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojKm.png)

Comment: I'm guessing that you already read [the Advanced Google services guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marti. Yes. I tried many of the different recommendations there - but to no success.

Comment: There isn't an advanced settings link either, right?

Comment: Yes - there is no link like that..

Comment: Your code works for me so it's not that. Are you using a gmail account, right?

Comment: yes I'm using a personal gmail account. If this will make any difference - I used to use a student GCP account (around 2018), but the trial period ran out and I didn't renew.

Comment: Could you try creating a new Apps Script project and copying the code there?